# How to use this script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, wget

```
#!\bin\bash
for i in `seq 1 1000`;
do
wget -q -O quotes http://www.quotedb.com/quote/quote.php?action=random_quote;
cat quotes>>final.txt;
done
```

I got this script from one website but I don't know how to use it.

I know php,html,JavaScript,jquery etc.

Can anyone help me using this script?

Comment: it seems you didn't tried nothing, right? do you want to know how to run a shell script in unix, or you are looking for a description of what this script does?

Comment: And the first line of your script looks wrong, it should be "#!/bin/bash" with slashes in the UNIX direction (except maybe on Cygwin??)

Comment: make it executable `chmod 755 /path/to/the/script` and execute it `/path/to/the/script`

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are using a shared hosting server and do not have a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shell script. You will need to create a file with extension .sh.

In linux terminal you will need to run the command as below.

> sh script.sh

Comment: ok it will work on live server?

Comment: Ok sure you can try. It will definitely work for you. It shows that it will write the output of the command in the file final.txt . Have you used Linux before ?

Comment: no thats why i am asking silly questions, Can you please guide me ?

Comment: Its ok, its not necessary that all knows everything. I know Linux well but don't know about programming. if you have any other issues with Linux you can ping me on my skype(keyur_081).

Comment: Actually i was finding shell in my hosting server but didnt find that.

Comment: For that you will need to share your screen with me. Please add me on my skype so i can help you out. Skype (keyur_081).

Comment: Please don't propagate the use of sh to run bash scripts: on many systems, `sh` is not `bash` and this will result in syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

This script will get 1000 quotes from the web-site www.quotedb.com.  It will first store the quote in the file named 'quotes' and then append the new quote to the file named 'final.txt'.
It is probably designed to collect quotes for a program such as 'fortune' which some people used to print on their screen when they login or open a shell. It will still require some clean-up as the returned quotes contain php script.

Comment: Thanks @quintablet that i know but i dont know how to use that.